# How to compare AM/PM time in Android

Tags: java, android, time, calendar

I have a scenario

```
start-time = 4:15 PM
end-time = 2:00 AM
```

if my `current-time` (let say 9:15 PM in the same format as start or end time) fall between `start-time` and `end-time` then goto `screen 1` other wise goto `screen 2`

My question is how do I compare `current-time` greater or equals to 'start-time' and less or equals to 'end-time'. I have tried by converting given time values into `milliseconds` and compare it but the `current-time = 9:15 PM` is appeared to be greater than 'end-time = 2:00 AM', as 2:00 AM will come after mid night means if `9:15 PM day = Thursday then 2:00 AM will be the Friday'. I have searching a lot but can't figure it out. Any type of help will be appreciated.

**EDITED:**

current-time, start-time and end-time all values taken to be as `String`

**EDIT 2**

code spinet:

```
long currentTime = getMillis("9:15 PM");

long startTime = getMillis("4:15 PM");

long endTime = getMillis("2:00 AM");//this will be the next day's time confusing part for me

if(currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime)
{
   //goto screen 1
}
else
{
  // goto screen 2
}


private long getMillis(String givenTime)
{
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
try {
    Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenTime);
    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    return timeInMilliseconds;
} catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the time?. As a Time instance? or as part of a Date instance or as part of a Calendar instance or just as a String?

Comment: how are you compare those objects. Can you post some code?

Comment: can you use 24hr fromat for time ?

Comment: @blackbelt I edited my question with code

Comment: @XtreemDeveloper: Checkout my answer, I have tested and it is working fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1:**
You simply need to **add a day to your end time when it is lower than your start time**.

**Step 2:**
**Apply your conditions** to check whether current time falls in between start time and end time or not

```
    try {
        Date mToday = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        String curTime = sdf.format(mToday);
        Date start = sdf.parse("4:15 PM");
        Date end = sdf.parse("2:00 AM");
        Date userDate = sdf.parse(curTime);

        if(end.before(start))
        {
            Calendar mCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            mCal.setTime(end);
            mCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            end.setTime(mCal.getTimeInMillis());
        }

        Log.d("curTime", userDate.toString());
        Log.d("start", start.toString());
        Log.d("end", end.toString());


        if (userDate.after(start) && userDate.before(end)) {
            Log.d("result", "falls between start and end , go to screen 1 ");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("result", "does not fall between start and end , go to screen 2 ");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // Invalid date was entered
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Date dt = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String curTime = sdf.format(dt);
Date start = parser.parse("4:15 PM");
Date end = parser.parse("2:00 AM");

try {
    Date userDate = parser.parse(curTime);
    if (userDate.after(start)){
      ....
      //you can have your if...else if... conditions 
    }
    if(userDate.before(end)) {
        ....
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Invalid date was entered
}
```

Comment: Your way is right.. But this will still fail in his case. Your code assumes the same day, the OP wants 2 am > 5 pm (i.e, implicitly assuming 2 am is the next day).

Comment: Yeah, right.. What i think is, In case of Time Comparison, we can not compare with the next day, we might also require Date if we want to consider the next day 2am

Comment: @TheLostMind: Exactly, and I made that implicit thinking to work like explicit

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal: Yes, we need the date for comparison, I used Calendar for current instance and tweaked with conditions.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal : I have not posted question. I have posted the answer. and yes I did +1 your answer as I have used it and enhanced.

Answer (score 1):

Use a date-time library that supports a time-only value without a date or time zone.

In the Java world, we have two good date-time libraries: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and java.time (bundled with Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310). Both libraries offer a [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class.

## Joda-Time

Here is some **untested** code in Joda-Time 2.4 to get you in the right direction.

```
String inputStart = "4:15 PM";
String inputStop = "2:00 AM";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "h:mm a" );
LocalTime start = formatter.parseLocalTime( inputStart );
LocalTime stop = formatter.parseLocalTime( inputStop );
String now = LocalTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );

boolean isNowInRange = false;
if( start.isEqual( stop ) ) {
    isNowInRange = ( now.isEqual( start ) );
} else if ( start.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    isNowInRange = ( ( now.isEqual( start ) || now.isAfter( start ) ) && now.isBefore( stop ) );
} else if ( start.isAfter( stop ) ) {
    isNowInRange = ( ( now.isEqual( start ) || now.isAfter( start ) ) || now.isBefore( stop ) );
} else {
    // FIXME: Handle this supposedly impossible case.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, you could do this. You are *lazy* (some small code would do this), so am I

> 1. if start time contains "AM" and current time contains "AM", then just check for values of both to know which one is bigger.
> 2. If 1 is true, then if end-time is pm, then return true. Else, check if current time < end time and return true/false.

PS : Follow the same approach if you have PM in case-1. Also, this is *certainly*, not a good way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to get the current date int timestamp(long millisec)

```
   Long dateTs;
    Date dateToday = new Date();
    String s = dateToday.toString();
    s = s.substring(4, 10) + ", " + s.substring(30, 34);
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .parse(s);
        dateTs = date.getTime();   // today 00:00 hours
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

Similarly, you can get timestamp for any datetime you want
```

and then simply compare timestamp with if else from current date.. i can explan more if you feel need for.